# HTML - Span tag is leaving two characters

Tags: html

I was writing a HTML code for my blog,
and once I've used span tag

```html
<span name="home">Home</span>
```

I could not see the clear text but this: 
`Home />`

What can I do, to see clear text?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You must have a `/>` after the span element somewhere in your page.  You haven't listed all of the code, so we can't see it.  Try using http://htmltidy.net/ to double check your work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "clear text"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to close an HTML tag declaration before you can write new tags.

So, `<div <span>Some text</span> />` is incorrect. To correctly nest tags, use:

```
 <div>
   <span>Some text</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: You have a misconception about the way HTML tags work. Study about XML.

Or quickly take a look at the fixed version:

https://jsfiddle.net/vxcrmrbw/

Comment: Thank you, alexpirine! It works. I understand what mistake I made.